# Androidx Recyclerview inside NestedScrollView

Tags: android

I have a `RecyclerView` inside a `NestedScrollView` but it is not scrollable. If I just have the `RecyclerView` by itself it is working fine so I was wondering if there are some missing attributes that I have forgotten to set.

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            android:overScrollMode="always"
            android:id="@+id/mRecyclerView"/>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

I have also tried setting the xml attribute `android:nestedScrollingEnabled` to true but that has not worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false); in code or   android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" in your xml